# change value of element in list c++

Tags: c++, list, atoi, c-str

this is what im doing, im getting some info from a .txt file those are numbers of course when im getting them i get them as strings in a list of strings...(i know it could be chars but in this example is strings) so when im inserting them on another list it should be something like this

```
list<int> l;

//i is the iterator for the 1st list that already has all the strings
l.push_back(atoi(*i.c_str()));
```

i cant use c_str() because i is trying to access the elements of the list is there anyway i can do this?

**basically what im trying to do is just getting my strings from one list and change them to integers while keeping the list format**

any help would be really appreciated thank you

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but if I did, isn't it just `i->c_str()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `(*i).c_str()` or `i->c_str()`.

You probably want to do the job as a whole a bit differently, specifically in a way that doesn't require you to deal directly with iterators at all. For example, let's assume what you have is:

```
list<string> strings;
list<int> ints;
```

Then I'd almost certainly do the job with `std::transform`, probably something like this:

```
std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(ints),
    [](std::string const &in) { return atoi(in.c_str()); });
```

or:

```
transform(begin(strings), end(strings), std::back_inserter(ints),
          [](string const &in) { return stoi(in); });
```

In case you're not familiar with it, that last line is a lambda (new with C++11). Assuming you're using a fairly new compiler (e.g., gcc 4.7.x or newer, VC++ 2010 or newer) it shouldn't be a problem.

I'd also seriously consider using `std::vector` instead of `std::list`. I've virtually never found `std::list` to be a particularly good choice. Even situations that should theoretically favor a linked list usually don't, at least in my experience.

Comment: If you're going to use C++11, you may as well use `std::stoi` too. :-]

Comment: With `std::vector`, you'll also benefit from calling `ints.reserve(strings.size())` beforehand.

Comment: wow awesome answer yeah im using c++11 but im still not used to it thank you very much

Comment: @Makenshi: As you can see from ildjarn's comment, I'm not yet accustomed to everything it's added either.

Comment: Isn't a lambda overkill on the stoi example? Anything wrong with `transform(begin(strings), end(strings), stoi)` ?

Comment: @ZanLynx : `stoi` is overloaded for `std::string` and `std::wstring`, so I think you would need an explicit cast in order for that to compile.

Comment: @ildjarn: This was a great excuse to download VS Express 2012. You were correct. A lambda appears necessary.